# View and Template for m2m with Through

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In my app i need to store invoices (Invoice) of known products (Product) to calculate points for each seller (User). I'm trying to create form to insert basic invoice data plus inline form with sold products info. To handle it i create model like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = False)
    mark = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True)
    points = models.IntegerField(blank = False)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(blank=False)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='Sold')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class Sold(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

I tried to manage it via django-admin and it work fine with admin.py:

```
class ProductTabular(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Invoice.product.through


class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductTabular]
    exclude = ('product', )

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice


admin.site.register(Invoice, InvoiceAdmin)
```

but i'm unable to create such form in own templates. Please, can you help me with views.py and template to get same result as for the django-admin?

I tried via invoce form with inlineformset_factory for the Sold model, but i can't figure out how to save it. Thanks for any help!